# Why is my radio options still checked when I'm click next button?

Tags: reactjs

I have asked this question yesterday but it seems like I asked it in the wrong way or I haven't explained it clearly so no one answered me back yesterday.

This is when I check the radio option

[image: Checking the radio option]

But when i'm clicking the next button, the next question will still be checked at the same radio position that I've checked at previous question, I thought when i'm clicking to the next button, all the answer will be unchecked for user to choose again. And those previous questions will stay checked the answers they choose when i'm click previous to display it again...

[image: After clicking the next button]

Edit: Here are my code from yesterday I posted, I'll including some comment, if you can help me, thanks!

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {Component} from 'react'

class QuizForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
                        step: 0,
                        dataQuestion: [],
                        question: 1,
                        answer: [],
                        groupQues: [],
        }
    }
// -I get the list of question based on quiz_ID, then all the answers based on question_ID at the same time, i'll send picture or json below
        async componentDidMount(){
            await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/quiz/'+this.props.quizID)
            .then(res=>{
                this.setState({
                    dataQuestion: res.data
                })
            })
            .then (()=>{
                let grouped = this.state.dataQuestion.reduce((acc, obj) => {
          const property = obj['question_ID'];
          acc[property] = acc[property] || [];
          acc[property].push(obj);
          return acc;
    }, {});
            this.setState({groupQues: grouped}) 
            })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
// -For moving to next or previous question by using index
        handleNext = ()=>{
        let grouped = this.state.dataQuestion.reduce((acc, obj) => {
          const property = obj['question_ID'];
          acc[property] = acc[property] || [];
          acc[property].push(obj);
          return acc;
    }, {});

        if (this.state.step === Object.keys(grouped).length - 1){
            return
        }
        this.setState({step: this.state.step + 1})
        this.setState({question: this.state.question+1})

    }
    handlePrevious = ()=>{
        if(this.state.step === 0){
            return
        }
        this.setState({step: this.state.step - 1})
        this.setState({question: this.state.question-1})
    }
 /---------------
    render(){
            const {question} = this.state
        return(
            <>
            <div className="column middle">
            <div className="game-details-container">
                <h1> Question : <span id="question-number"></span>{question}/{Object.keys(this.state.groupQues).length}</h1>
            </div>
                    <div className="game-quiz-container">    
                                        {this.state.groupQues[Object.keys(this.state.groupQues)[this.state.step]]?.[0].question_desc}
                        <div className="game-options-container">
// - I'm using map to get answers based on same question_ID, example, question_ID 1 has 3 answers based on it.

                                <form>
                          {this.state.groupQues[Object.keys(this.state.groupQues)[this.state.step]]?.map(element=>
                                {
                                return(
// -I set different radio id, name based on the quiz_description, label, too
                                <>
                                <input type="radio" id={element.answer_ID} name={element.question_desc} value={element.answer_result}></input>
                                <label htmlFor={element.question_desc}>
//- Display answer description
                                {element.answer_desc}
                                </label>
                                </>
                                        )
                                    }               
                                )}
                                </form>                       
                        </div>
                        <div className="next-button-container">
                            <button onClick = {()=>this.handlePrevious()}>Previous Question</button>
                            <button onClick = {()=>this.handleNext()}>Next Question</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                </>
        );
    }
}
export default QuizForm
```

This is how dataQuestion display:

```
[
    {
        "question_ID": 13,
        "question_desc": "Question 1",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 17,
        "answer_desc": "A",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 13,
        "question_desc": "Question 1",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 18,
        "answer_desc": "B",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 13,
        "question_desc": "Question 1",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 19,
        "answer_desc": "C",
        "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 14,
        "question_desc": "Question 2",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 20,
        "answer_desc": "A",
        "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 14,
        "question_desc": "Question 2",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 21,
        "answer_desc": "B",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 15,
        "question_desc": "Question 3",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 22,
        "answer_desc": "A",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 15,
        "question_desc": "Question 3",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 23,
        "answer_desc": "B",
        "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 16,
        "question_desc": "Question 4",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 24,
        "answer_desc": "A",
        "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 16,
        "question_desc": "Question 4",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 25,
        "answer_desc": "B",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 17,
        "question_desc": "Question 5",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 26,
        "answer_desc": "Testing Answer",
        "answer_result": 0
    }
]
```

This is when i group it together based on question_ID so I can using array.map for it, it's call groupQues in my code:

```
{
  "13": [
    {
      "question_ID": 13,
      "question_desc": "Question 1",
      "quiz_ID": 6,
      "answer_ID": 17,
      "answer_desc": "A",
      "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
      "question_ID": 13,
      "question_desc": "Question 1",
      "quiz_ID": 6,
      "answer_ID": 18,
      "answer_desc": "B",
      "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
      "question_ID": 13,
      "question_desc": "Question 1",
      "quiz_ID": 6,
      "answer_ID": 19,
      "answer_desc": "C",
      "answer_result": 0
    }
  ],
  "14": [
    {
      "question_ID": 14,
      "question_desc": "Question 2",
      "quiz_ID": 6,
      "answer_ID": 20,
      "answer_desc": "A",
      "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
      "question_ID": 14,
      "question_desc": "Question 2",
      "quiz_ID": 6,
      "answer_ID": 21,
      "answer_desc": "B",
      "answer_result": 1
    }
  ],
  "15": [
    {
      "question_ID": 15,
      "question_desc": "Question 3",
      "quiz_ID": 6,
      "answer_ID": 22,
      "answer_desc": "A",
      "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
      "question_ID": 15,
      "question_desc": "Question 3",
      "quiz_ID": 6,
      "answer_ID": 23,
      "answer_desc": "B",
      "answer_result": 0
    }
  ],
  "16": [
    {
      "question_ID": 16,
      "question_desc": "Question 4",
      "quiz_ID": 6,
      "answer_ID": 24,
      "answer_desc": "A",
      "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
      "question_ID": 16,
      "question_desc": "Question 4",
      "quiz_ID": 6,
      "answer_ID": 25,
      "answer_desc": "B",
      "answer_result": 1
    }
  ],
  "17": [
    {
      "question_ID": 17,
      "question_desc": "Question 5",
      "quiz_ID": 6,
      "answer_ID": 26,
      "answer_desc": "Testing Answer",
      "answer_result": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Update: I have manage to log the value out, and Example: Question 1 has A B C answers, I can select one of these A B C, it'll log out value, if I press next question, the new answer will be all unselect, and the previous question will still be selected, that's what I want.
But when I select the new answer from the next question, the previous answer from previous question will immediately be unselect.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Component } from "react";

class QuizForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            step: 0,
            dataQuestion: [],
            question: 1,
            answer: [],
            groupQues: [],
//- I add this selectedRadio state in
            selectedRadio: null,
        };
    }
    // ------------------
    async componentDidMount() {
        await axios
            .get("http://localhost:3000/quiz/" + this.props.quizID)
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    dataQuestion: res.data,
                });
            })
            .then(() => {
                let grouped = this.state.dataQuestion.reduce((acc, obj) => {
                    const property = obj["question_ID"];
                    acc[property] = acc[property] || [];
                    acc[property].push(obj);
                    return acc;
                }, {});
                this.setState({ groupQues: grouped });
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
    // -------------------
    handleNext = () => {
        let grouped = this.state.dataQuestion.reduce((acc, obj) => {
            const property = obj["question_ID"];
            acc[property] = acc[property] || [];
            acc[property].push(obj);
            return acc;
        }, {});

        if (this.state.step === Object.keys(grouped).length - 1) {
            return;
        }
        this.setState({ step: this.state.step + 1 });
        this.setState({ question: this.state.question + 1 });
        // this.setState({selectedRadio: null})
    };
    handlePrevious = () => {
        if (this.state.step === 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.setState({ step: this.state.step - 1 });
        this.setState({ question: this.state.question - 1 });
    };
//- I add this new method in
    select = (answer_ID) => {
        this.setState({ selectedRadio: answer_ID });
    };
    // ---------------------
    render() {
        const { question } = this.state;
        console.log(this.state.selectedRadio);
        return (
            <>
                <div className="column middle">
                    <div className="game-details-container">
                        <h1>
                            {" "}
                            Question : <span id="question-number"></span>
                            {question}/{Object.keys(this.state.groupQues).length}
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="game-quiz-container">
                        {
                            this.state.groupQues[
                                Object.keys(this.state.groupQues)[this.state.step]
                            ]?.[0].question_desc
                        }
                        <div className="game-options-container">
                            {this.state.groupQues[
                                Object.keys(this.state.groupQues)[this.state.step]
                            ]?.map((element) => {
                                return (
//- I insert checked and onChange for the radio input
                                    <>
                                        <div key={element.answer_ID}>
                                            <input
                                                type="radio"
                                                checked={this.state.selectedRadio === element.answer_ID}
                                                id={element.answer_ID}
                                                name={element.question_desc}
                                                value={element.answer_result}
                                                onChange={this.select.bind(this, element.answer_ID)}
                                            />
                                            <label htmlFor={element.question_desc}>
                                                {element.answer_desc}
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </>
                                );
                            })}
                        </div>
                        <div className="next-button-container">
                            <button onClick={() => this.handlePrevious()}>
                                Previous Question
                            </button>
                            <button onClick={() => this.handleNext()}>Next Question</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
export default QuizForm;
```

Comment: you ahve to clear object field where you are storing that radio button's value

Comment: This one is harder than I expected, I can't just figure it out, I do some research when you told me this, can you give me more instruction, I set the State to false, and in the array.map I use onClick to setState it back to true, but whenever I click, it's keep select the last options, like A B C, it'll get C options, A B it'll just always select B, and it's doesn't empty all select options when I click next button, too

Comment: you can log them to check whether the value is even changing or not

Comment: I log them out and see the value is changing, I have managed somehow, for example: at Question 1, I have A B C answer, if I check 1 of those, when I click next, the all next answers will be blank, and the previous will still stay in check, that's what I want, but the new problem is when I check the new answer (at Question 2), the answer from Question 1 will be unchecked, this confusing me a little bit, can you take a look at my code again, I will update it.

Comment: It's kind of a state
It's like updating when you check on question 2 what happens is it updates those values
as same key value pairs are being used

Comment: Do you have anyways so I can continue progress, I'm kinda stuck on this problem, like... I have no more solution I can think of anymore.

Comment: I can suggest you to match your case with vue working 
itskidn of similar